# Sync Windows Mobile and Window Hotmail Calendar via USB

Tags: windows, hotmail, activesync

I want to sync my Windows Mobile Phone with the Windows Live Mail Calendar (Windows 7), since I don't have WLAN. I tried syncing the phone directly with Windows Hotmail, but ActiveSync seems to only sync with the computer connected to it, not any other server address (though I have Internet access via USB).

I can't seem to setup Windows Live Mail as my default Calendar application and so Windows Mobile Center keeps telling me that Outlook is not installed, therefore no syncing available. 
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Live Mail is not Outlook, and, I do not think ActiveSync has ever worked properly (if at all) with Outlook Express/Windows Mail/Windows Live Mail.

All I can suggest is trying to acquire a copy of Outlook and try again.

Alternatively, I have not tested this solution, but, it looks like the device should support over the air push calendar - [read this guide](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/08/30/hotmail-now-supports-push-email-calendar-and-contacts-with-exchange-activesync.aspx) - If this is just a PDA and not a phone, without wireless, I am not sure of a better solution other than installing Outlook.